# How to fix the font size or cells size in tables

Tags: tables, fontsize, columns, cellspace

i want to fix the font size or cell size to do the table looks better.
My code is as follow:

```
\begin{table}
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{0.17\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Posición} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Características}}\\ 
    \midrule
    \textbf{Defensas} & \% Duelos defensivos ganados & \% Duelos aéreos ganados & \% Pases correctos & Faltas cada 90 minutos \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Mediocampistas} & \% Pases correctos & Intercepciones cada 90 minutos & \% Duelos defensivos ganados & \% Duelos ofensivos ganados \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Delanteros} & \% Duelos ofensivos ganados & \% Remates al arco & Asistencias cada 90 minutos & \% Centros correctos \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla variables distancia euclediana}
\end{table}
```

How can i fix this problem with the size? I leave a photo so you can see the result that I have so far.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Se. Does this answer your question? [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)

Comment: Probably you're more satisfied with the outut if you use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}@{}}`. (Needs the `tabularx` and `ragged2e` packages).

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but I'd also replace both `\hline` commands with `\addlinespace`. Mixin lines from the `booktabs` package with regular `\hline`s results in an inconsistent spacing around the lines and thouse two are nevertheless not really needed to provide structure for the table. I'd also replace `\midrule` with `\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-5}`.